# Ini files and Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an app that I am developing for Android which contains 4 Tedit objects.
The user has to enter specific data into the Tedits and this is then processed with a Tbutton onclick event.  What I would like to be able to do, is save the last user input to something like an ini file, which can be read back when the app is accessed again.  This ini could be updated by the Tbutton onclick event and read back with the forms onactivate or oncreate events.  I have done this with VCL applications but am totally at a loss as to where to start with Android.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You can use `TMemIniFile`, it works on all platforms

Comment: I have used TIniFile and it is very good, just call the Update on the object to be sure that the data are saved!

Comment: What's preventing you from just trying for yourself? What exactly do you expect us to tell you?

Comment: I have managed to use TMeminifile and it works perfectly in Win64 and Win32 modes.  My issue is that when deployed to an Android device I get an error message 'Cannot Create File "wol.ini" not a directory."  For Win32 and 64 the ini file is created in the applications executable folder.  I am assuming that with Android I must be more specific with where the ini is created, but having little or no understanding of where ini files should be located I am struggling a little.

Comment: INI files should be in the user folder, not in the executable folder... on all platforms. Check out TPath.GetDocumentsPath